# Vanishing Chern-Simons partition function

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, quantum-anomalies, chern-simons-theory

I was reading again the article ["Generalized Global Symmetries"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.5148) and I notice that in the beginning of page 22, they argue that after gauging the $\mathbb{Z}_k$ one-form symmetry, of Chern-Simons theory, the partition function vanishes. Therefore, indicating a 't Hooft anomaly.

So, basically, the claim is that
$$
Z=\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}\int \mathcal{D}a W_n[a] \exp\left(i\int \frac{k}{4\pi} a\wedge da\right)
$$
is equal to zero, where $W_n[a]$ denotes the Wilson loop operators responsible for gauging the discrete symmetry.

However, I do not understand why this must be the case, can some please clarify this for me ?

Comment: are you sure that's the claim? usually gauging a one-form symmetry involves summing over $H^1$, so there should be a triple sum (assuming you are looking at a 3-torus).

Comment: Maybe I miss something then. When gauging a discrete symmetry, they just mention that we must sum over all possible insertion, I thought we should do what I wrote in the question. Could you recommend some reference about this for me ?

Comment: The Wilson loop depends on $n$ and $a$, but also on the path you insert it in. In a 3-torus, there are three independent loops you can choose to insert $W$ in. Summing over all possible insertions means, what you wrote, but inserted in all these three cycles (hence, three sums like that).